Site crashes with "Attempted to create, modify or delete an instance of field with name X on entity type Y when the field storage does not exist."
I apologize for the long post. I'm just trying to be thorough on what is happening and what I've tried so far...
For a while (at least six months) I've been having issues with my website crashing, always in a "slow" manner, always with the same error message. I say "slowly" because it crashes one page at a time, i.e., while most pages are still live, a few others start to give the traditional "Temporarily Unavailable" message. As time passes, if I don't take any actions, more and more pages crash with the same error message.
When this happens, I open "php-errors.log" and find a number of entries (sometimes a dozen, sometimes more than a hundred) with a message like this:
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Field\FieldException: "Attempted to create, modify or delete an instance of field with name "X" on entity type "Y" when the field storage does not exist."

(in most cases, there will be multiple entries of the same field/entity combination, e.g., if I have one hundred records, there will be 20 or 30 repetitions of about 3 to 5 different field/entity combinations. Those 3 to 5 combinations are always the same for all crashes).
I did some research online and found lots of articles talking about this error message, usually repeating what the message itself says, i.e., that the field in question is lacking its associated field storage configuration file (field.storage.xxxx.yml), or that the field storage configuration file is not properly defined inside the field configuration file itself (field.field.XXXX.yml).
So I went through the 300+ field configuration files ("field.field.xxxx.yml") and confirmed that each one has its associated field storage configuration (field.storage.xxxx.yml). I've also confirmed that the field storage configuration file is properly defined as a dependency inside the field configuration file itself.
Some articles say that to stop the error messages, all I have to do is to open the field definition in the backend of Drupal (for example, "Structure > Content Types > my-custom-type > Manage Fields"), edit that field and, without making any changes, save it. And so, each time there's a crash, I go to each field/entity combination that appears in php-errors.log and save it again (without changing anything).
To bring the site back up, all I have to do is rebuild cache (drush cr). Interesting enough, I have to run it twice as the first time it always gives me the same error message as above ("Attempted to create, modify ..."). The second time always succeeds on rebuilding the cache and bringing the site back online.
A few final points:

I use composer to keep my site up-to-date, with deployments from local to dev to staging to production.
Each time I save a field (without changes), I ensure that no changes happened to the configuration of the field itself. If changes happened, I incorporate them to my local code. These changes are always "innocuous", i.e., a new attribute with an empty, false, null, or zero value.
After each deployment to production I have to save the fields again in the backend. As soon as the deployment ends, errors start to pop on php-errors.log right away and only re-saving those fields stop them from continuing which would innevitably lead to a site crash.
I've installed the "Devel Entity Updates" module and, from time to time I enable, run the drush command (drush entity-updates), but it gives me no pending chates/updates.
I've dealt with all error messages in my "Status Report" page, even those most likely not related to this issue and those that were not really errors like the use of external CDN libraries for JavaScript (Drupal recommends they be loaded locally).
My site is hosted in Acquia with all its layers of caching (I bring this up because the issue might either cause or be caused by cache corruption).

So, any ideas on what is the root cause of this issue?
Thanks,
Alex
